# Best way to check function parameters: Check for null or try/catch

Tags: c#, exception, methods, robustness

when implementing/using methods that return or work with instances of objects, what is the most elegant approach to check the function parameters ?

Method to call:

```
someType GetSomething(object x)
{
    if (x == null) {
        return;
    }

    //
    // Code...
    //
}
```

or better:

```
someType GetSomething(object x)
{
    if (x == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("x");
    }

    //
    // Code...
    //
}
```

Calling Method:

```
void SomeOtherMethod()
{
    someType myType = GetSomething(someObject);

    if (someType == null) {
        return;
    }

}
```

or better:

```
void SomeOtherMethod()
{
    try {
        someType myType = GetSomething(someObject);
    } catch (ArgumentNullException) {
    }
}
```

When browsing through similar questions, the reason not to use try/catch is performance. But IMHO the try-catch just looks better :).

So, which way is more "elegant"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If passing in a `null` is not valid, throw an exception (i.e. - this is an exceptional situation that should *never* happen).

If a `null` parameter *is* valid, return a corresponding object.

In general, accepting `null` parameters is **bad practice** - it goes against the principle of least surprise and requires the caller to *know* it is valid.

Comment: Having functions that will evaluate non-null inputs, and return null for null inputs, is often a useful pattern.  In some cases, the Null Object Pattern may be nicer, but it can be hard to implement with generics.

Answer (score 4):

As far as elegance is concerned, it's hard to top [Code Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/dd491992.aspx).

```
Contract.Requires(x != null);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should only use exceptions for exceptional cases.  If you expect the argument might be (legitimately) null, you should check it -- do not use exceptions for that.  IMO you should check for null at the calling site (*before* the invocation) if it doesn't make sense to pass null to your method.

Answer (score 0):

In your example GetSomthing is private. This means you can track down all of the callers and make sure that Null values don't get passed in e.g.

```
 if (x != null)
   someType myType = GetSomthing(x)
 else
   // Initialize  x or throw an InvalidOperation or return whatever is correct
```

However if its not really private then you should do as Oded and others said. Check to see if its null and throw an ArguementExecption in most cases.